# fwidth(uv) giving strange results in glsl

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures, glsl, antialiasing

I checked the result of the [filter-width](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/fwidth.xhtml) GLSL function by coloring it in red on a plane around the camera.

The result is a bizarre pattern. I thought that it would be a circular gradient on the plane extending around the camera relative to distance. The further pixels uniformly represent more distant UV coordinates between pixels at further distances.

Why isn't `fwidth(UV)` a simple gradient as a function of distance from the camera? I don't understand how it would work properly if it isn't, because I want to anti-alias pixels as a function of amplitude of the UV coordinates between them.

```
float width = fwidth(i.uv)*.2;  
return float4(width,0,0,1)*(2*i.color);
```

UVs that are close = black, and far = red.

Result:
[image]

the above pattern from fwidth is axis aligned, and has 1 axis of symmetry. it couldnt anti-alias 2 axis checkerboard or an n-axis texture of perlin noise or a radial checkerboard:

```
float2 xy0 = float2(i.uv.x , i.uv.z) + float2(-0.5, -0.5); 
float c0 = length(xy0); //sqrt of xx+yy, polar coordinate radius math
float r0 = atan2(i.uv.x-.5,i.uv.z-.5);//angle polar coordinate      
float ww =round(sin(c0* freq) *sin(r0* 50)*.5+.5) ;
```

Axis independent aliasing pattern:[image]

Answer (score 1):

The mipmaping and filtering parameters are determined by the partial derivatives of the texture coordinates in screen space, *not the distance* (actually as soon as the fragment stage kicks in, there's no such thing as distance anymore).

I suggest you replace the fwidth visualization with a procedurally generated checkerboard (i.e. `(mod(uv.s * k, 1) > 0.5)*(mod(uv.t * k, 1) < 0.5)`), where k is a scaling parameter) you'll see that the "density" of the checkerboard (and the aliasing artifacts) is the highst, where you've got the most red in your picture.

Comment: I am sorry i have to disagree. If i rotate the checkerboard, the aliasing pattern is related to it's rotation. Same with a round checkerboard using polar coordinates, the aliasing is uniform around the camera. Aliasing of a texture cannot be axis aligned(except for a checkerboard), however the red pattern from fwidth is axis aligned... i'll prove my point in another way. the red pattern is essentially a () shape, it has 1 axis of symmetry, UVx, and the checkerboard has 2 axes of symmetry, UVy and UVy, so one doesnt correlate with the other. radial has n axes of symmetry.

Comment: float2 xy0 = float2(i.uv.x , i.uv.z) + float2(-0.5, -0.5);    
    float c0 = length(xy0); //sqrt of xx+yy, polar coordinate radius math     
    float r0 = atan2(i.uv.x-.5,i.uv.z-.5);//angle polar coordinate         
    float ww =round(sin(c0* freq) *sin(r0* 50)*.5+.5) ;//radial checkerboard

Comment: instead of fwidth, this works to estimate the uv amplitudes between pixels:  -  *float ww = length( ddx(uv) - ddy(uv) );*    -  i think the tutorials on antialiasing procedural textures are misleading because they use fwidth, i.e. gpugems tutorial.

Comment: sorry Datenwolf, i forgot to mention that fwidth(UV) pattern was not rotating with the camera, it's fixed relative to objects. so fwidth(UV) shouldnt be used for antialising things like checkerboards.